AWS Route53 MX Records for Google Workspace Domain
I have a client who bought a domain from Google several years ago, in order to develop the website that he wanted I needed to transfer the domain to AWS route 53 so that I could create a hosted zone under the same domain so that the client and server can interact without worrying about 3rd party cookie issues.
I have managed to transfer the domain from SquareSpace to AWS (Squarespace bought google domains service). I am now in the middle of deploying the site but my client has said that he is not getting emails under his google workspace domain which is the same domain as the website. Looks like the MX records from Squarespace were not considered important and not part of the transfer to AWS route 53
I am trying to fix this issue but I am not very familiar with DNS configuration.
Below is the current configuration of the domain DNS.

I have blocked out the domain name and specific addresses but consider the domain as example.com.
I have put in the MX records for gmail that I have found recommended but when I test an email under the workspace I don't get the mail.
I have two A records, one for the client and one for the server but no CNAME record.
It seems like I am missing something because when I dig the domain, I do not get any address back only "example.com IN A".
It is hard for me to tell if this is just a consequence of the delay it takes for the records to be propagated or if the records are incorrectly configured.
My priority is to get the email working/google workspaces back up and running and I can work through the rest later.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

I think I have found the source of the issue. It looks like the whois record for my domain has NS records pointing to the google domain servers and I need those NS records to be the AWS ones. I think this should have been done during the transfer but apparently SquareSpace doesn't do that. So now I have to try and get the domain registrar to change the NS records to the new AWS NS records before I can do anything else. I think that is correct, if someone thinks this is wrong, please let me know.

To ensure your Google Workspace email functions securely and reliably, you should also set up additional DNS records such as SPF (Sender Policy Framework), DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail), and DMARC (Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting & Conformance). These records help prevent email spoofing, improve email deliverability, and enhance security.
(root domain) or mail   MX  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM  1

(root domain) or mail   MX  ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5

(root domain) or mail   MX  ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5

(root domain) or mail   MX  ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 10

(root domain) or mail   MX  ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 10

(root domain) or mail   TXT v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all N/A

google._domainkey (DKIM)    TXT v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqh... (public key string from Google)  N/A

_dmarc  TXT v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:dmarc-reports@example.com    N/A

SPF: Use ~all or -all at the end of the SPF record. ~all is softer and means "soft fail" (messages that don't pass SPF will be marked as suspicious but not rejected). -all means "fail" (messages will be rejected if they don't pass SPF).
DKIM: Once you add the DKIM record and enable authentication in Google Admin, it may take several hours for the record to propagate.
DMARC: The p=quarantine option is recommended to start. Once you're confident that email is being authenticated correctly, you can change it to p=reject to reject emails that fail DMARC.
